# How to display custom Emoji's that are not in the Unicode character table in an iOS App?

Tags: iphone, ios5, graphics, unicode-string, emoji

After searching the web for a couple of hours, I didn't get any solution to the following problem:

I am creating a new iOS app which is able to display [existing Emoji](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/) in the Unicode character table. Now I also want to be able to create and display custom Emoji characters, but how should I map this using Unicode?

Is it even possible to use and display custom Emoji in iOS apps using Unicode? How should I go about this?

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the problem. Emoji's are implemented as font glyphs, within a font. So if you want to design new ones, you have to get a font creation tool, find some unicode space (ie numbers) that won't collide with other characters, the create your font. When you would use the characters, you switch to your font for just those characters.

Comment: am facing similar problem... did u get solution?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this url will help you
http://punchdrunker.github.com/iOSEmoji/table_html/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the post, but these are our existing unicodes, I also have posted link in my question for the same.